# How to select a file or folder with custom tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I’m working on a project with a GUI. It was using the Python `tkinter` library. I wanted to make it more modern and I turned to `customtkinter`, prettier. At one point in my application, the program asked the user to choose a folder and I used the `filedialog.askdirectory()` method.

Unfortunately, I can’t find an alternative to this one in `customtkinter` (it uses indeed the visual of `tkinter`, very old and ugly, I think).

Do you know if there is a similar method in `customtkinter`? If not, would you have an alternative?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/1079) was posted as an issue on `customtkinter`'s GitHub. Basically if you want something nicer, you will have to either build it yourself using a window and widgets or use another GUI framework.

Comment: This is the official CustomTkinter documentation  --> https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/

Comment: ca you use tkinter tkinter.filedialog — File selection dialogs  https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog ??

Comment: @pippo1980 OP said that *"visual of `tkinter` [is] very old and ugly,"*

Comment: then its @TheLizzard way .. OP will have to either build it OPself or use another GUI framework

Comment: @TheLizzard, I understood that customtkinter did not offer this possibility. But do you have an alternative with a modern design?

Comment: @Tim240 I haven't use any GUI framework apart from `tkinter`. If there is something that doesn't look well, I just spend a week re-implementing it from scratch like [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/Bismuth-184/blob/main/screenshot.png). From that GitHub repo, you can prob get the file selector and copy it in your own project but the code is quite messy.

Comment: Okay. @TheLizzard, thanks for all your answers. I am new in stack overflow, do I have to close the question ?

Comment: @Tim240 Leave it open or write an answer of your own.

Comment: Why don't you try out ttkbootstrap. It features a much more modern style and has the typical Windows like popup windows for the filebrows, etc... https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/